# how to post form in MVC 3.0 razor on radio button change

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I want to active and inactive user account on click on form post. I am using

```
   @using (Ajax.BeginForm("SetStatus", "Home", null, new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod = "Post" }, null))
                            {
                                  if (res.Status == 1)
                                  { 

                                        <span class="userStatusSpan statusActive"><input type="radio" name="status" value="1" checked="checked" />Active</span>
                                        <span class="userStatusSpan statusInactive"><input type="radio" name="status" value="0"  />Inactive</span>
                                  }
                                  else
                                  {
                                         <span class="userStatusSpan statusActive"><input type="radio" name="status" value="1" />Active</span>
                                        <span class="userStatusSpan statusInactive"><input type="radio" name="status" checked="checked" value="0"  />Inactive</span>

                                  }
                          }
```

Can anyone please tell me how to post form on check box change?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can call below javascript function onclick event of your radio button.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function submitform()
      {
        document.myform.submit();
      } 
    </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion in this case better to use plain jQuery ajax post. Some example you can find here: [Submit form when checkbox is checked - tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2421510/157666)

Answer (score 0):

Just go for document.formid.submit();