# Submit form when a radiobox is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, form-submit

I've read a few questions that meet this description but I'm still struggling. I've read this [submit-form-when-checkbox-is-checked-tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421445/submit-form-when-checkbox-is-checked-tutorial)

Can't seem to get a form to submit when a radiobox is checked. I've tried using `.click` and `.on('change')`

Here is my code, the jquery is in a php loop.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {                      
        $('input[name=choice-<?php echo $id; ?>]').click(function() {
            $('#assessment-form-<?php echo $id; ?>').submit(function(e) {                       
                alert('It works :)');
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

```html
<form id="assessment-form-456" method="post" action="">
    <ul class="clearfix">
        <li><input type="radio" name="choice-456" id="t-456" value="yes">Yes</li>
        <li><input type="radio" name="choice-456" id="f-456" value="no">No</li>
        <li><input type="radio" name="choice-456" id="na-456" value="na">n/a</li>
    </ul>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: You are not submiting the form but on each click **binding** a new submit handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your problem:

```
$('#assessment-form-<?php echo $id; ?>').submit(function(e) {  
       alert('It works :)');
});
```

Instead of submitting the form, you are adding an event listener that will trigger when the form is submitted.

You should not pass any arguments to the function:

```
$('#assessment-form-<?php echo $id; ?>').submit();
```

See the jQuery [manual](https://api.jquery.com/submit/); you need the shortcut for the trigger method in order to trigger the form submit.

Answer (score 0):

It attribute values should be wrapped in quotes :

```
  $('input[name="choice-<?php echo $id; ?>]"')
```

Like this one :

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {

   $('input[name="choice-456"]').change(function() {
     alert('It works :)');
     $('#assessment-form-456').submit();
   });

 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="assessment-form-456" method="post" action="">

  <ul class="clearfix">
    <li>
      <input type="radio" name="choice-456" id="t-456" value="yes">Yes</li>
    <li>
      <input type="radio" name="choice-456" id="f-456" value="no">No</li>
    <li>
      <input type="radio" name="choice-456" id="na-456" value="na">n/a</li>
  </ul>

  <input type="submit">

</form>
```